# Why can't other users join my Agora channel using a token generated from my hosted token server on Railway?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, agora

When i use the agora console to generate token, anybody can join the channel. But when i use the agora token server i hosted on railway to generate a token. other users can not join the channel using the token generated. Here is my my VideoCall component code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useClient, useMicrophoneAndCameraTracks, appId } from './settings';
import Controls from './Control';
import Videos from './Video';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const VideoCall = ({ setInCall, token, channelName, userId }) => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  console.log('users*****', users);

  const client = useClient();
  const [start, setStart] = useState(false);
  const { ready, tracks } = useMicrophoneAndCameraTracks();

  useEffect(() => {
    let init = async (name) => {
      client.on('user-published', async (user, mediaType) => {
        await client.subscribe(user, mediaType);
        console.log('subscribe success');
        if (mediaType === 'audio') {
          user.audioTrack?.play();
        }
      });

      client.on('user-unpublished', (user, type) => {
        console.log('unpublished', user, type);
        if (type === 'audio') {
          user.audioTrack?.stop();
        }
      });

      client.on('user-left', (user) => {
        console.log('leaving', user);
        setUsers((prevUsers) => {
          return prevUsers.filter((User) => User.uid !== user.uid);
        });
      });

      await client.join(appId, name, token, userId);

      // Subscribe to the user's own tracks if they exist
      if (tracks) {
        setUsers((prevUsers) => [...prevUsers, client]);
        await client.publish([tracks[0], tracks[1]]);
      }

      setStart(true);
    };

    if (ready && tracks) {
      console.log('init ready');
      init(channelName, userId);
    }
  }, [channelName, client, ready, tracks, token, userId]);

  return (
    <StyleWrapper>
      <div className="wrapper">
        {start && tracks && <Videos users={users} tracks={tracks} />}
        {ready && tracks && (
          <div className="control">
            <Controls
              tracks={tracks}
              setStart={setStart}
              setInCall={setInCall}
            />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </StyleWrapper>
  );
};

export default VideoCall;

const StyleWrapper = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  .wrapper {
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 90vh;
  }
  .control {
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    left: 50px;
    bottom: 50px;
  }
`;
```

Is there anything i'm not doing correctly

I tried making the userId an array just maybe only the uids stored for a channel can access the channel. But how token server accept uid not an array of uid

or is this possible
https://agora-node-token-server-production-1de4.up.railway.app/rtc/my-channel/publisher/uid/100,200/?expiry=86400